# image file attachment on email not sent properly through PHP

Tags: php, image, email, attachment

I'm using the `mail()` function to test sending emails with image file attachments to myself.
The problem with the script is that when I look at the email, I see a long wall of random numbers, letters, and symbols where an image is supposed to be.

Please don't recommend PHPmailer or manually putting in an image tag in the message body.

The main PHP file I'm using:

```
<?

 include('init.php'); 

if (isset($_POST['name'], $_FILES['file'])){

    $body = <<<BODY
    From: {$_POST['name']}

    Details: 
        Name:   {$_FILES['file']['name']}
        Size:   {$_FILES['file']['size']}
        Type:   {$_FILES['file']['type']}

BODY;

mail_file('receiver@email.com','test@php.com','a file upload',$body,$_FILES['file']);   
}

?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
   <input type="submit" value="Email File">
</form>
```

init.php:

```
<?

$path = dirname(__FILE__);
include("{$path}/mail.php");

?>
```

mail.php:

```
<? 

function mail_file($to, $from, $subject, $body, $file){
    $boundary = md5(rand());

    $headers = array(
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"{$boundary}\"",
        "From: {$from}"
    );

    $message = array(
        "--{$boundary}",
        'Content-Type: text/html',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit',
        '',
        chunk_split($body),
        "--{$boundary}",
        "Content-Type: {$file['type']}; name=\"{$file['name']}\"",
        "Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"{$file['name']}\"",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
        '',
        chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']))),
        "--{$boundary}--"
    );

    mail($to, $subject, implode('\r\n', $message), implode('\r\n', $headers));
}
?>
```

Example of an email sent:

```
--4f8b4f63eb5fb4f1c3cde903c7e5b306\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n    From: asas

Details: 
Name: 728x90-Brink-Banner-V2.jpg
Size:   41583

Type:   image/jpeg

\r\n--4f8b4f63eb5fb4f1c3cde903c7e5b306\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg; name="728x90-Brink-Banner-V2.jpg"\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; name="728x90-Brink-Banner-V2.jpg"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAZABkAAD/7AARRHVja3kAAQAEAAAAUAAA/+4ADkFkb2JlAGTAAAAAAf/b
AIQAAgICAgICAgICAgMCAgIDBAMCAgMEBQQEBAQEBQYFBQUFBQUGBgcHCAcHBgkJCgoJCQwMDAwM
DAwMDAwMDAwMDAEDAwMFBAUJBgYJDQsJCw0PDg4ODg8PDAwMDAwPDwwMDAwMDA8MDAwMDAwMDAwM
DAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwM/8AAEQgAWgLYAwERAAIRAQMRAf/EAOgAAAAGAwEAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAMEBQYHCAECCQABAAAHAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkQAAEDAgUBBgMDBAsHDA0NAQEC



...


L81/7CT7TfOuj+7T/wCxbf6cmeeXwouVG4P5we/F/E/yvzHTHMh6q9MNzUc7m/T5X4f4h6fP+6uF
jIJbcyh7Z0b6/h/d6fbhYSHp7D+cIXk/RYHy/RU9P+y/j6sIk9VBmYV1+H+sf9B6Dz+b7cZufPat
RB6oyV2LP+B/6NfhD8X8X7Ph34OPJMy+so95T/RGP/NzzD+bfxuuFyeoozf1ozUXWfoz+n/jJ/Rv
P9n8XvxTvzWktcx8eSvxxR+Gn9P6p83k7Ov72JFl4VE1T1tngUtb2/mmd+H+iu/jfyD1xZyZKqhz
VHdz/wA4H9F/Aa6/h/oKPxP+y+GKmX4eNXtuv//Z
\r\n--4f8b4f63eb5fb4f1c3cde903c7e5b306--
```

Comment: Are you sure that content type is sent correctly? Thats might be the reason for data dump.

Comment: Also you might need to send the file size.

Comment: can you post sample source of email? Code looks OK, but maybe `mail()` is messing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem lies in here:

```
mail($to, $subject, implode('\r\n', $message), implode('\r\n', $headers));
```

You have used single quote and new line is treated as 4-charater string `\r\n`, change it to:

```
mail($to, $subject, implode("\r\n", $message), implode("\r\n", $headers));
```